# Proving a specific vector space with two operations

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, proof-explanation

> Prove that
>   $$V = \{ (a,b) \in \Bbb R^2 : a,b > 0 \}$$
>   is a vector space with the operations
>   $$(a,b) \oplus(c,d) = (ac,bd)  \,\,\,\forall  (a,b),(c,d) \in V$$
>   and
>   $$\alpha(a,b) = (a^\alpha,b^\alpha)\,\,\,\forall\alpha \in \Bbb R\,\,\,\forall(a,b) \in V.$$

I know that I must show the 8 properties but this $(ac,bd)$ is confusing me in two properties and the $\alpha$ exponent also is driving me crazy to show the multiplication properties.

Could anyone help?

Comment: You could consider whether you know a transformation of the plane which turns product to addition and powers to scaling ( hint coordinatewise logarithm)

Comment: To elaborate: I suggest to find a map to identify V with this algebraic structure with the full plane and the usual vector space structure. From there the vector space structure should be clear.

Comment: I really don't know if I really understood what you said. It seems a little strange but I'm gonna try it, there is another comment about this below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need closure first of all. Do the two operations in question produce vectors that are still in the space? The answer is yes; the multiplication of two positive numbers is positive, and a positive number raised to any real number is also positive. Check. Then we move on to:

1. Associativity of addition:
   \begin{align*}
   (a,b)\oplus((c,d)\oplus(e,f))&=(a,b)\oplus(ce,df)\\
   &=(a(ce),b(df))\\
   &=((ac)e,(bd)f)\\
   &=(ac,bd)\oplus(e,f)\\
   &=((a,b)\oplus(c,d))\oplus(e,f),
   \end{align*}
   as required.
2. Commutivity of addition. Perform a similar calculation as above; the result follows from the commutivity of real multiplication.
3. Identity element of addition. I think you'll find this is $(1,1):$
   \begin{align*}
   (a,b)\oplus(1,1)&=(a\cdot 1, b\cdot 1)\\
   &=(a,b)\\
   &=(1\cdot a,1\cdot b)\\
   &=(1,1)\oplus(a,b).
   \end{align*}
4. Inverse elements of addition. I think you'll find that, for vector $(a,b),$ its inverse is $(1/a,1/b).$ Note that $a,b>0,$ so this is defined. We'd have
   \begin{align*}
   (a,b)\oplus(1/a,1/b)&=(a/a,b/b)\\
   &=(1,1),
   \end{align*}
   the additive inverse. And you can check that the other direction of multiplication works as well.
5. Compatibility of scalar multiplication. This says that we need $a(b(c,d))=(ab)(c,d),$ where $a$ and $b$ are scalars. We have
   \begin{align*}
   a(b(c,d))&=a(c^b, d^b)\\
   &=((c^b)^a,(d^b)^a)\\
   &=(c^{ba},d^{ba})\\
   &=(ba)(c,d)\\
   &=(ab)(c,d),
   \end{align*}
   as required.
6. Identity element for scalar multiplication. This'd be $1:$
   $$1(a,b)=(a^1,b^1)=(a,b). $$
7. Distribution over vector addition. We need
   $$a((b,c)\oplus(d,e))=(a(b,c))\oplus(a(d,e)). $$
   So, we have
   \begin{align*}
   a((b,c)\oplus(d,e))&=a(bd,ce)\\
   &=((bd)^a,(ce)^a)\\
   &=(b^ad^a,c^ae^a)\\
   &=(b^a,c^a)\oplus(d^a,e^a)\\
   &=(a(b,c))\oplus(a(d,e)),
   \end{align*}
   as required.
8. I'll let you show that $(a+b)(c,d)=a(c,d)+b(c,d).$

Comment: Much work for something that is plainly a structure transfer through $\ln$ function component by component as underlined by @user587399

Comment: @JeanMarie: No doubt you are right. However, if the OP is being confused by the exponent, then talking about structure transfers would only confuse the issue more. You have to gauge your presentation to the audience.

Comment: Be sure that I appreciate your detailed and rigorous answer [+1], in compliance with "gauging one's presentation to the audience". However, I think that this point (structure transfer) should at least be mentionned as a remark for solving further problems of the same kind this student will surely encounter in maths studies.

Comment: I was trying to expand the multiplication just like

$$ a_1 + a_2 + ... + a_\alpha $$

Was I doing a big booboo?

Answer (score 0):

Consider the map $V \to \mathbb{R} \oplus \mathbb{R}$ that sends $(a, b)$ to $(\ln a, \ln b$). This map converts coordinatewise products into coordinatewise sums and coordinatewise powers into scalar multiples, and is a bijection. It follows that since the codomain is a vector space, so is the domain, and the map is in fact an isomorphism of vector spaces.